# Convert boolean metric/expression to a counter

Tags: prometheus

I need to convert a boolean metric to a counter to capture the increase in 0/1s. I am struggling to come up with a recording rule or a function to achieve this. What options are available to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going from a gauge (your boolean metric) to a counter is impossible. At least without losing data. E.g. given a scrape interval of 10 seconds, your boolean could flip to 0, then 1, then 0, then 1, etc. any number of times in that 10 second interval. It may even end up on the same value as it was 10 seconds ago.

So e.g. from a sequence like this with a flip every 5 seconds, Prometheus would only ever see the ones, never the zeroes:

```
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
  ^   ^   ^   ^   ^
```

So from Prometheus' point of view, your gauge is stuck at 1 and there's never any change to it.

Assuming your counter never changed more often than 10 seconds though, you could set up a recording rule like `changes(boolean_metric[20s])` (still assuming a scrape interval of 10 seconds) and then do a `sum_over_time()` over the output of that rule.